# UWP C# How to remove hyperlink Cues focus border?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

Is there anyway to remove `Hyperlink` focus border in windows universal platform as shown in image below?
[HyperLink Cues Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ8WZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want. Try this `UseSystemFocusVisuals="False"`.

Comment: `<Hyperlink>`does not have `UseSystemFocusVisuals` property so I changed the property for the `<Page>` element. But no change :( Am I doing wrong or something?